# Android Studio 2 Activities

Tags: java, android-studio

For Android studio, my question is how can I write(Java Code) an activity where avtivity 1 calls activity 2, and activity one sends a number to activity 2. After that the activity 2 prints this number out and increase it by one and sends it back to activity 1

thanks in advance and sorry if this already asked someone else

Comment: This is a reasonably basic concept of Android (and Java in general) programming.  Maybe try reading a book such as http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learn-Java-Android-Development/dp/1430264543 ?

Answer (score 1):

From these tutorials you will be able to make 2 Activities communicating with each other

Starting Another Activity
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Communicating with Other Fragments http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Getting a Result from an Activity
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is described here in the official documentation : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "delegate" method :

1st activity :

```
public class Activity1 implements AsyncResponse {

    ...

    public void printAndIncrement() {
        Activity2 activity2 = new Activity2();
        activity2.delegate = this;
        activity2.doWhatIWant(3);
        // destroy activity2
    }

    public void processFinish(int result) {
       // do something with the result
    }

}
```

2nd activity :

```
public class Activity2 {

    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    ...

    protected void doWhatIWant(int num1) {

        Systel.out.println(num);
        delegate.processFinish(num1+1);     

    }

}
```

(interface) :

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(int result);
}
```